# Change DIV background-color with Coffescript

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am currently doing the password strength indicator on Ruby on Rail web application, and I was wonder why I cannot **change the password indicator background-color** even when the validate status is good or strong, it is still in **red** color.

```
if (validatePassword.status ? 'weak')
    $('#validateMeter').css('background-color','red')
else if (validatePassword.status ? 'good' || 'strong')
    $('#validateMeter').css('background-color','green')
```

Is there any solution? Thank.
[image]

Comment: Not a solution- but for better separation of concerns, you may want to assign a class in your JS then define the presentation of the class in your CSS

Comment: i think this `validatePassword.status ? 'good' || 'strong'` check for the usage of the existential operator `?` in coffeescript

Comment: Removed an image which seemed to have been accidentally posted within the code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not entirely sure what should happen if the status is not defined (as you’re checking for that) but the following should work:

```
color = if validatePassword.status in ['good', 'strong'] then 'green' else 'red'

$('#validateMeter').css('background-color', color)
```

The code above will set the color to green if the `validatePassword.status` is `good` or `strong` otherwise it will be set to `red`.

Should you want to unset the color entirely, I’d recommend trying something along the lines of this:

```
color = switch validatePassword.status
  when 'weak'           then 'red'
  when 'good', 'strong' then 'green'
  else ''

$('#validateMeter').css('background-color', color)
```